# Flexslider main image open in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, flexslider

I want to open main image in fancybox when click on main image in flexslider.

If possible that when click on main image and open it in fancybox with all thumbnail as like display in flexslider with prev and next button.

How to do it possible? Is there any parameter in flexslider or need to do customization?

Please help me. I mention code here.

Thanks

**=> Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox.css"/>
      <script src="modernizr.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
         @import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/flexslider.min.css";
         body { font-family: avenir, sans-serif; }
         #slider .slides img {
         width: 450px;
         height: 300px;
         margin: 0 auto;
         }
         .container{
         max-width: 50%;
         margin : 0 auto;
         }
         #carousel .flex-active-slide img {
         opacity: 1;
         }
         #carousel img {
         opacity: 0.65;
         }
         .flex-direction-nav .flex-next { right: 0 !important; margin-right: -40px; }
         .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { left: 0 !important; margin-left: -40px; }
         .flex-control-thumbs li {width: 25%; float: left; margin: 0;}
         .flex-control-thumbs img {width: 100%; display: block; cursor: pointer;}
      </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(window).load(function() {
                    $('#carousel').flexslider({
                      animation: "slide",
                      controlNav: false,
                      animationLoop: false,
                      slideshow: false,
                      itemWidth: 70,
                      itemMargin: 10,
                      asNavFor: '#slider'
                    });

                    $('#slider').flexslider({
                      animation: "slide",
                      controlNav: false,
                      animationLoop: false,
                      slideshow: false,
                      sync: "#carousel"
                    });
            });
            $('#carousel li').click(function() {
              $('#carousel li').removeClass('flex-active-slide')
              $(this).addClass('flex-active-slide');
            });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- Include jQuery library and Flexslider script -->
      <!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
      <div class="container">
         <div id="slider" class="flexslider" onclick="func(this)">
            <ul class="slides">
               <li>
                  <img src="1.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="2.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="3.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="4.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="5.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="6.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="7.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="8.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="1.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="2.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="3.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="4.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="5.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="6.jpg" />
               </li>
               <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
               <li>
                  <img src="1.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="2.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="3.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="4.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="5.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="6.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="7.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="8.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="1.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="2.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="3.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="4.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="5.jpg" />
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="6.jpg" />
               </li>
               <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fancyBox works with any slider/carousel, you just have to iniatialise using `.selector` option and you have to tweak this to suit your needs, e.g., this selector has to return visible links and has to exclude duplicates. Something like this:

```
$().fancybox({
  selector : '.slides li:not(.clone) a'
});
```

Here are demos using

- Slick - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/pdbrjx
- OwlCarousel2 - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/mqvOoz
- Swiper - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/eWVyVg
- flexslider - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/QQdXwx

Comment: I kind of hoped you would do that :P

Comment: I tried to do that. But it's not working so. It's very useful for me if you make codepen demo of flexslider with fancybox.

Comment: I want to do exactly like your all codepen example. Main image and thumbnails both are open in fancybox

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to display only 4 thumbnail like 65x65 px in flexslider?

Comment: You mean something like this - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VQPJam ? Use `itemWidth` option for that. Check flexbox demos - http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html

Comment: Yes. Exactly. But, when thumbnail image size is big then thumbnail also display in big size. I just want to set thumbnail size max 65x65 px and display only 4 thumbnail. If I set itemwidth 210 then it'll display 4 thumbnail but size is too big. But, I want in only 65px.

Comment: Sorry, I have never used flexlider, maybe try asking new question here :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/RjRQzm => In this codepen, How zooming functionality is working. Can you please tell me ? @Janis It's your codepen. So, I ask to you

Comment: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments"